# Disk icons on desktop

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gnome-shell, .desktop, shortcuts

On 18.04 LTS a mounted internal disk (other than the boot disk) and a mounted share included in `fstab` appear on the desktop without further intervention.

This appears not to be the case with 20.04.1.
The drives are perfectly selectable from within `nautilus` and are mounted in `/media/`.

Is this the new norm or have I missed a trick somewhere along the way?
This is a vanilla installation of 20.04.1 from scratch on a new PC.

Comment: From my understanding in order for your mounted drives to appear on the desktop they have to be mounted in the `/media/` folder.  Also, depending on what Desktop Environment you are using i.e. Xubuntu, GNOME, etc. you might need the icons for Removable Drives selected to show them on the desktop in the settings.

Comment: @Terrance Question updated to address your points/queries. Thanks

Comment: Well, when I go to my GNOME desktop I can't turn on the icons for removable drives for the desktop icons.  I tried looking at https://extensions.gnome.org and I am not seeing anything there for them as well.  Maybe this is the new norm for GNOME.  I don't use GNOME by default so I don't think that I would be much more help beyond this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one that works.  You do need to make sure that no other Desktop Icon extensions are enabled.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/ and enable it to show those mounted drive icons on the desktop.

[image]

Example showing them enabled:

[image]

Comment: brilliant!! works perfectly. Thanks